# URL shortening options for EE5?

Tags: url

Are there any options to add URL shortening abilities from inside EE5? Looking for something to tie into a Bitly or TinyURL account. There were options for EE2 and EE3, but they were abandoned.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you want the shorterned URLs to do?  Is it simply to offer a short alternative to existing templates / pages within EE, or do you plan to capture 'dynamic' urls reflecting a session activity (e.g. including GET parameters etc.).  Both are possible, former much easier to implement than latter.  Also, would be useful to know what version of EE you are using ... :)

Comment: Sure. Using EE 5.3.2. Specifically, I was hoping for an updated version of Shortcut by Solspace, which was abandoned at EE3. You can see the legacy documentation here: https://solspace.com/expressionengine/legacy/shortcut

I can get around this using Detour by EE:Harbor, but it's not as elegant.

Comment: To clarify, I can manually generate shortened urls using Detour, but it has to be under the same domain. It's not quite the same as Bitly or TinyURL.

Comment: You don't need Detour to create a short URL if you are using your own domain, but I understand that the Detour UI is easy to use and so perhaps useful.
If you want to create a short URL using someone else's domain (e.g. bit.ly, or solsp.ac) you will need an API to talk to their server for it to work - which at very least will need an add-on on your EE system to interact with it.

Comment: Detour just makes it easy for the client to set redirects, for campaigns or advertising, which is what I'm after. Good idea with the API. Maybe if I can't find a plugin to do this within EE, I can tie into an API to show bit.ly options on the front end. Still, the old EE2 plugins were very handy. Sad they were never translated to EE5.